# Gray out Background when menu is toggled

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, navigation, sass

So I have a link that displays a menu. When that menu is visible (expanded) I need the background to go dark. So here is what i am trying.

```
if($('.expanded').html){
  $('nav').css("height", ($(window).height()))
};
```

So that when the .expanded class is toggled on and off it should work (doesn't of course)

Here is my toggle:

```
$('.js .menu-button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  $('[role="navigation"]').slideToggle('fast', function() {});
});
```

and here is the SASS

```
nav
  padding: 0
  margin: 0
  +transparent(#000, .6)
  width: 100%
```

So when that "expanded" is toggled the transparent black in the css should cover the whole viewport

Any help on this is much appreciated.

I also tried to do it this way:

```
$('.js .menu-button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  $('[role="navigation"]').slideToggle('fast', function() {});
  $('nav').css("height", ($(window).height()))
});
```

This turns the dark background on but then i can't turn it off.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-button"></div>
  <nav> 
  <ul role="navigation" id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Stay</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hotel Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Buzz</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Local Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Things to Do</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Offers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: how your first snippet is related to your click handler?

Comment: @F.Calderan It isn't it is just looking for a class of expanded.

Comment: @F.Calderan I edited my original post to show another way i was trying that did use the click handler but that was only 50% right.

Comment: Are you using any jquery plugin to make your menu? Could you add part of your menu's html and/or share a jsfiddle link to test it?

Comment: @FlavioCysne I added the html. I am working on getting a jsfiddle working

Comment: I am trying to do this based on flexnav https://github.com/indyplanets/flexnav

Comment: You are aware of the issue with inherited opacity I trust? If the menu list is a child of the element you want to "knock out" the page with it will inherit the 0.6 opacity. A much better way to do this is to have (or dynamically insert) a <div> at the end of your DOM which has height/witdh 100% and position absolute. You show/hide this <div> to toggle the background fade and simply place the menu list on top of it. The same <div> can be reused for popups etc. Let me know if this might work for you and I can give a fuller example.

Comment: @olaTuvesson I am aware of that however that is not at all what I am doing. I am applying a background color with an opacity like rgba. That will not affect any child elements.

Comment: @AHdezigns - Fair enough, but then you lose support for IE 6, 7 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simple set the dark background in the click() function()?

```
$('.js .menu-button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  //test for expanded class
  if ($(this).hasClass('expanded'))
  {
     //turn something dark

  }
  else
  {
     //remove dark
  }

  $('[role="navigation"]').slideToggle('fast', function() {});
  $('nav').css("height", ($(window).height()))
});
```